# Way to visualize schemacrawler output in web application

Tags: schemacrawler

Can anybody suggest a good way to visualize schemacrawler output in a webapplication. I need the output as ER diragram. is there any good javascript or jquery plugin which uses DOT format? One more thing when i try to get the output in the dot format it is giving the output as

## System Information

SchemaCrawler Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-

product name                              SchemaCrawler
product version                           12.04.02

Database Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-

database product name                     MySQL
database product version                  5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
database user name                        demo@localhost

JDBC Driver Information
-=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=--=-

driver name                               MySQL Connector Java
driver version                            mysql-connector-java-5.1.34 ( Revision: jess.balint@oracle.com-20141014163213-wqbwpf1ok2kvo1om )
driver class name                         com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url                                       jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
is JDBC compliant                         false

## Tables

### demodb.dbconnection

```
                                                             [table]
```

id                                INT NOT NULL
                                    auto-incremented
  dbmsType                          VARCHAR(100)
  ipAddress                         VARCHAR(100)
  port                              VARCHAR(10)
  username                          VARCHAR(100)
                                    This table is used to store database connections
  password                          VARCHAR(100)
  databaseName                      VARCHAR(100)

```
                                                       [primary key]
```

id                                ascending
                                    auto-incremented

### demodb.roles

```
                                                             [table]
```

roleId                            INT NOT NULL
  roleName                          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL

```
                                                       [primary key]
```

roleId                            ascending

### demodb.userdetails

```
                                                             [table]
```

id                                INT NOT NULL
                                    auto-incremented
  name                              VARCHAR(45)
  dob                               DATE
  sex                               VARCHAR(1)
  bloodgroup                        VARCHAR(5)
  address                           VARCHAR(45)
  place                             VARCHAR(45)
  city                              VARCHAR(45)
  state                             VARCHAR(45)
  country                           VARCHAR(45)
  zipcode                           VARCHAR(45)
  mobile                            VARCHAR(45)
  email                             VARCHAR(45)
  occupation                        VARCHAR(45)

```
                                                       [primary key]
```

id                                ascending
                                    auto-incremented

```
                                       [foreign key, with no action]
```

id <-- demodb.`user`.userDetailsId

### demodb.userroles

```
                                                             [table]
```

id                                INT NOT NULL
                                    auto-incremented
  username                          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
  roleName                          VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL

```
                                                       [primary key]
```

id                                ascending
                                    auto-incremented

### demodb.`user`

```
                                                             [table]
```

username                          VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  password                          VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
  userDetailsId                     INT NOT NULL
  active                            INT NOT NULL

```
                                                       [primary key]
```

username                          ascending

```
                                       [foreign key, with no action]
```

userDetailsId --> demodb.userdetails.id

```
                                                  [non-unique index]
```

userDetailsId                     ascending

```
                                                      [unique index]
```

username                          ascending

and my schemacrawler-context.xml is like

```
<bean id="outputOptions" class="schemacrawler.tools.options.OutputOptions">
    <property name="outputFormatValue" value="DOT" />
    <!-- <property name="outputFile" value="scOutput.txt" /> --><!-- This should be given(writer not file) given from the program. -->
</bean>
```

it is not working for DOT as well as dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Khader,

For web output, you have a few output options available out of the box from SchemaCrawler. One option is to generate output in "htmlx" format, which will give you an ER diagram embedded in HTML, in a single file. Another option is to use "png" format to generate a PNG file. It is hard to see what executable you have in the Spring context, since you have not included this key information in your question. I would advise you to use the GraphExecutable.

Please note that in order to generate the ER diagram, you will need [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed on the web server. [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) will always generate a file, and cannot use a Java writer. So, please use the most appropriate constructor for [OutputOptions](http://goo.gl/9MCFzP).

If you like, you can have SchemaCrawler generate DOT format. Again, please use the most appropriate constructor for [OutputOptions](http://goo.gl/9MCFzP). You do not need GraphViz for this. You can use [viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/) to visualize the DOT file using JavaScript.

Hope this helps.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks sualeh for you comment. My spring context is available in a post that you answered. Please refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118381/schemacrawler-returning-tables-from-all-available-databases. In that i am using SchemaTextExecutable and provided output format as DOT but is is giving an output as above. Should i use Graph executable in order to generate DOT format? Our preference is viz.js as we need to add operations on the generated ER diagram like selecting table from Diagram etc. Also can you please provide a link to get Java docs for schemacrawler?

Comment: I have one more doubt, while i am using GraphExecutable there is a .dot file always created in temp folder even though output file is provided via OutputOptions. Is there any way to avoid the temp file creation and to get the dot file in a string or byte[] format?

Comment: I don't have your email with me. Please send me you email ID.